# Reading any string coming from Arduino

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am developing an application to read data through Serial Port. What I am trying to read is a `string` that could be empty or with something in it.

My first attempt was creating an array where inside of it I would be able to insert what could come from Serial Port.

```
string[] pass = new string[4];
pass[0] = "";
pass[1] = "Something";
pass[2] = "To";
pass[3] = "Read";

for (int i = 0; i < pass.Length; i++)
{
    string element = pass[i];
}
```

But this isn't work for me because I wanna read any thing from the Serial port.
In the next option, in the `data.ToString() == "Any string I want"`.

```
string data = serPort.ReadExisting();
if (data.ToString() == "Any string I want")
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Basically, instead of the `"Any string I want"` I would like to every time I send something through the Arduino it will be recognized by the application.

Do you guys have any suggestions about this? In other words, if the incoming data is equal to the string written by the Arduino it will do something.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I've updated the question... @MichaelFaisst

Comment: Are you asking how to compare two strings?

Comment: I don't know if my code is right, but I want to read a string and continue with the code @J.McCabe

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, and how it relates to your "serial port" tag

Answer (score 0):

You  need to decide on a termination char and add it to your arduino code that is sending the serial string and look for that char in the incoming data. I'm using carriage Return line feed.

```
    private string receivedDate = string.Empty;
    private System.IO.Ports.SerialPort mport;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mport = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None,8, StopBits.One);
        mport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(mport_DataReceived);
    }

    private void mport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        receivedDate += mport.ReadExisting();
        if (receivedDate.Contains("\r\n"))
        {
            //show data
            //Clear receivedDate

        }

    }
```